# mysql query optimiser

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query written in mysql that is taking, what feels like, a ridiculous amount of time to complete.  I really need to speed this query up, it is taking in excess of 7 hours to complete.  There are 2 million row in the table that it is querying - historic_runner_races.  I have thought about lots of different ways that I can optimise this,  I have also tried sql server in case that was quicker.  I have investigated all different types of index combinations and found that they didn't really make a massive difference in the over all run time.

The query is

```
    insert into smartform.historic_jockey
    SELECT runners.id, 
     ( select count(1) 
      FROM smartform.historic_runners_races ru
     where ru.jockey_id = runners.jockey_id 
     and ru.race_id < runners.race_id 
     and ru.finish_position =  1
     ) jockeyWins

    FROM smartform.historic_runners_races as runners ;
```

I am really at a loss with this. The index's I have are on runner_is, race_id, and then jockey_id, race_id, finish_position.

Any advice is gratefully received.

Laura

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.  There may be alternate ways to express the logic.

Comment: Have you run only the select query separately ? How much time does it take ? Please give explain statement result for your select query. As well as Create table statement with indexing details

Comment: How does the SELECT perform by itself, without the INSERT INTO portion?

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
insert into smartform.historic_jockey (runner_id, jockyWins )
    select runners.id, 
           (select count(1) 
            from smartform.historic_runners_races ru
            where ru.jockey_id = runners.jockey_id and
                  ru.race_id < runners.race_id and
                  ru.finish_position =  1
           ) as jockeyWins
    from smartform.historic_runners_races runners ;
```

For this query, you want an index on `historic_runners_races(jocky_id, finish_position, race_id)`.  Run the `select` independently and see if that helps.

Comment: Thinking if we add the`id` column to that index (as the last column), then the index will become a "covering index" and the query may be even faster. Upvoting anyway.

Comment: @TheImpaler note that the primary key is already implicitly at the end of every index in InnoDB.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You are absolutely right. All secondary indexes in InnoDB cannot have a ROWID (no such thing), but have the PK instead.